# How to disable drag on a WPF TextEdit control of a listbox draggable item

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop

I Have a WPF listbox and are using the GongSolutions.Wpf.DragDrop so the drag drop can be handled in the bound ViewModel.

My listbox is using an ItemTemplate, where each item is a UserControl that is basically just a panel with a TextBox.

When I try and select text within the text box, a drag operation starts. I would like to disable this drag operation just for this TextBox.

Would anyone know how to do this, and if particular when using the GongSolutions.Wpf.DragDrop library?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, upgrading to the latest version fixed this.